# Memory using is increasing continuously with every navigation. and crash after 4-5 minutes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In my app,i have around 50 nib  files.And i Used ARC on..means with automatic reference counting .. i used navigation controller for navigation.so With every navigation memory indicator in x-code is continuous increasing..and crash..any solution for memory management 
?

Comment: how do you instantiate them and how do you segue?

Comment: i m using xib.and making object of that class with pushviewcontroller and poviewcontroller...

Comment: I mean where/how you create the view controllers before you push them (initwithnibname line).

Comment: This may be because of strong reference(s) created to controllers in your code. Are you assigning VC to any `strong` properties? Show your code.

Comment: @Amar not single variable is strong..

Comment: @indianarmy Without looking at the code, I can just guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided us enough information to diagnose your problem. Could be leaks (such as that caused by strong reference cycles, e.g. sloppy use of repeating timers). Could be abandoned memory (such as caused by some circular logic in your navigation). No way to diagnose on the basis of what you've shared thus far.

I'd suggest you watch WWDC 2013 video, [Fixing Memory Leaks](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?include=410#410) (for registered developers). This builds upon the WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=242#242), which you might want to watch first. These walk you through the categories of problems and introduce you to some techniques for using Instruments to diagnose the problem.

Comment: i have no memory leaks and not declared any property as a strong...i think the reason is may be cycle of navigation   so any soilution??

Comment: @indianarmy First, identify what precisely is not getting released. You can use Instruments (as shown in those videos), use app a bit, take snapshots/generation, use the app a bit more and get back to the original spot, take another snapshot/generation, and that will show you (in excruciating detail, what objects were allocated between the those 2 points in time. Dig through the second snapshot/generation details, and you'll figure out what precisely is taking up your memory, and you can start your analysis there. Don't guess; use Instruments.

Answer (score 1):

To navigate instantly back and forth to plenty of view controllers , you should use `UIPageViewController` , you can go through the documentation provided by apple at the below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

You can also navigate back and forth by swiping the screen as well when you have implemented `UIPageViewController` , if you would like to stop that behavior at that time you can disable the horizontal scrolling of pages: